# Checar se há string em um array multidimensional PHP

Tags: php, array, laravel, array-multidimensional

Tenho o seguinte array:

```
array => [
  "c2_unid" => array:2 [
    0 => {
      "tipologia": "Tipologia"
    }
    1 => {
      "c2_unid": "Tipo"
    }
  ]
  "c1_unid" => array:2 [
    0 => {
      "disponibilidade": "Disponibilidade"
    }
    1 => {
      "c1_unid": "Unidade"
    }
  ]
]
```

Preciso checar nos arrays com nomenclatura "c1_unid, c2_unid..." sempre no array de posição 0(primeiro) há a palavra "disponibilidade".

OBS: os arrays com nomenclatura "unid" é dinâmico podendo chegar mais ou menos arrays.

Comment: Mas o que você espera que tenha no retorno? Você quer apenas que se em qualquer um dois c*_unid tenha a palavra "disponibilidade", ou você quer realizar um ação ao encontrar estes valores, em resumo, o que você quer fazer ao encontrar este valor?

Comment: eu precisava de um retorno true ou false comparando e as chaves desse array com as chaves de outro, consegui com a resposta abaixo e mais uns exemplo que encontrei. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar a função `every()`, disponível nas collections (https://laravel.com/docs/collections#method-every):

```php
return collect($yourArray)->every(function ($value, $key) {
    return $value === 'Disponibilidade';
});
```